# Question on dice rolling -- expected number of rolls to get a particular sequence

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, markov-chains, expected-value

Came across this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/933329/219483) to problem on expected number of dice rolls to get 1,2,3,4,5,6. I reproduce it below:

For $i=1$ to $n$, define Bernoulli random variables $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if at $i$ we have the beginning of the sequence $123456$, and by $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $Y=\sum_1^n X_i$ is the number of times the sequence $123456$ appears.

By the linearity of expectation, we have $E(Y)=\sum_1^n E(X_i)$. But for any $i$ which is not too large, $E(X_i)=\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{6^6}$. It follows that $E(Y)=\frac{n-5}{6^6}$.

---

I believe I follow the solution. But it seems like, if we go for any other sequence, like 111222, I would get the same result, since the linearity of expectation doesn't require random variables be independent.

Though intuitively,  111222 should have fewer expected number of rolls than 123456? Since for 123456, I have to get reach roll exactly right, otherwise I have to start over for the desired sequence. But for 111222, it doesn't matter if I get 10 1's in a row, as long as I get next roll = 2, I can keep going? i.e., I don't have to "start over", I can resume halfway. Actually, [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488292/219483) explicity pointed out that for other sequences, the number of rolls are different.

So, does the provided answer doesn't work for arbitrary sequence? If not, why?

**[EDIT after Joriki's answer]** My main question is why the linearity of expectation doesn't work. Yes I get that in the approach of linearity of expectation, we are looking for n such that E(y)=1, which might be a different question from "expected number of rolls until we hit 123456", but I struggle to understand why they are different.

Comment: @imranfat I disagree. I think you can try to use markov chains to compute the expected number of rolls to get 1,1,1. it will be smaller than 1,2,3

Comment: Yes, that actually makes sense. If 2 equal strings can "overlap" it changes the expectation. I think the link you referred to is worth looking into

Comment: https://www.untrammeledmind.com/2020/02/dice-probability-expected-rolls-to-see-all-six-sides-coupon-collectors-problem/ this might be helpful too

Comment: In general, the expected waiting time if string $S$ is the sum of the reciprocals of the frequencies of those substrings of $S$ which occur as both initial and final substrings (e.g. for $S=434343$, the substrings are $43, 4343, 434343$). For $123456$ or $111222$, there are no proper overlapping substrings, so the EWT is $1$ / frequency (i.e. $6^6$ rolls for a fair die).

Comment: Also, the expected waiting time for $111$ will be MORE than for $123$. For $123$ it with $216$ rolls, and for $111$ it will be $216+36+6 = 258$, due to the proper overlapping substrings $11$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood the first question you linked to, possibly due to its ungrammatical formulation. The first linked question says “we count the number of time when the sequence $123456$ appears”, which is unclear because it’s ungrammatical, but the rest of the question suggests that the intended meaning was “we count the number of times the sequence $123456$ appears”, and this is accordingly also the formulation used in the accepted answer.

Your question about the expected number of rolls to get $123456$ (which is also the question asked in the second question you linked to) is a very different question – the answer is much larger (of the order of $6^6$ instead of $6^{-6}$); it cannot be answered by just applying linearity of expectation; and you’re right in thinking that the answer to this question does depend on the particular sequence.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I misunderstood. Though I still have question on why the linearity of expectation doesn't work. Yes I get that in the approach of linearity of expectation, we are looking for $n$ such that $E(y) = 1$, which might be a different question from "expected number of rolls until we hit 123456", but I struggle to understand why they are different.

Comment: @Vendetta: The reciprocal of the expected number of occurrences per roll is the expected number of rolls between two occurrences. This is the correct part of your intuition. The incorrect part is if you then equate the expected number of rolls between two occurrences with the expected number of rolls starting from scratch.

Comment: Occurrences of $11$ cluster together, whereas occurrences of $12$ don't, so whereas both have the same number of occurrences per roll and the same average number of rolls between occurrences, you have to wait longer for $11$ than for $12$ starting from scratch, since the distances within a cluster are $1$ and this has to be compensated by longer waiting times between clusters to get the same average number of rolls between occurrences. As for the linearity of expectation, it always works, you're just equating the wrong expectations.

Comment: Thanks, now I get full clarity.